# Powershell: Search object list for variable value?

Tags: powershell, scripting

I am working on a script for some of my users to identify if they have the current required Windows hotfix installed.

I am trying to put the KB number in a variable so I don't have to hardcode it within the script, but I am not having any luck. When I replace the $1809 in the get-hotfix line with the actual 'KB4577668', it returns the correct value of "TRUE". But when I leave it as the variable, it returns "FALSE" which is not correct. Any ideas?

```
    $1809 = "KB4577668"
    (get-hotfix).hotfixID -contains $1809
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$1809 = "KB4577668"

#method 1
$Founded=Get-HotFix -id  $1809

#or method 2
$Founded=Get-HotFix | where HotFixID -eq $1809

#test result
if($Founded)
{
  "hotfix founded"
}
else
{
  "hotfix not founded"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string seems to be fixed which is a literal string, so if you are not using variables in the string enclosed with speech marks, then using single quotes is advised.

`$1809 = 'KB4577668'`

More information on this from the Microsoft documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.1

and also another article from Microsoft Scripting Guy,

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/weekend-scripter-understanding-quotation-marks-in-powershell/